# Javascript function declaration. When to use what?

Tags: javascript, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

What is the reason you would do:

```
somename = function(param1, param2) { }
```

In stead of doing:

```
function somename(param1, param2) { }
```

Comment: Basically they are the same, but the first one is called `function literal notation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fn = function(param1, param2)
```

By using the above form you are able to pass $fn to any function as a parameter, or you could create a new object from that:

```
function doSomethingWithFn($fn);
```

or

```
$fnObject = new $fn(param1, param2)
```

You can use the second form when you just need a utility function, or for closures:

```
function utilityFn(str) {
    return str.indexOf('a')
}
var str = utilityFn('abc');
```

or

```
$('#element').click(function() {
    utiliyFn($('#element').html())
})
```

Comment: Not really. Functions created by either form can be used as function parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Well since the 1st syntax is a variable declaration and the 2nd is an actual function declaration, i would stick to the 2nd unless I truly needed the 1st.

Try to read up on scoping and variable hoisting and you will see that the 2nd syntax can sometimes create trouble for you :)

http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-function-declaration-ambiguity/

http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting

Btw, you might want to browser this thread and look for more good stuff: 
[var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: I understand. However what would be a situation when you would use de declaration of a variable way?

Comment: Well there are many places where you can use it, but few places where you need to. One that comes to mind, is if you use a 3rd party framework/library and have to overload an existing function in the library/framework.

Answer (score 0):

The first method creates a function object that you can then pass as parameter to other functions. For example, if you want to execute some code when a text box value changes, you can set a callback like this (using jQuery):

```
var onChange = function() { /* ... */ }
$("#username").change(onChange);
```

Comment: The second form (a *function declaration*) can be used that way too.